# 2005: The company hosts a (the?) annual meeting of the Petroleum Alliance

Tags: articles

Suppose we have a list of paragraphs reflecting a company's history through the years, and one of them reads:

> 2005: The company hosts **an (the?)** annual meeting of the Petroleum Alliance in Moscow, Russia.

Should we use *the* or *a* here?

The meeting is one of the many, and is introduced to the reader for the first time.

On the other hand, in that particular year (2005) there's only one installment of that meeting and the word *meeting* is postmodified by an of-phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The", because you more or less said it yourself. It's a "one-of-a-kind" in that it was the only edition of the meeting in that year.

Think of the subject as "annual meeting of xxx 2005". Since there is only one of such a thing, we would certainly use "the".

Another influencing factor in the sentence is "annual", which means "once a year". This also gives weight to my previous reasoning regarding "one-of-a-kind".